# Exception is not getting called in plsql

Tags: exception, plsql, oracle11g, spl

I am a beginner in plsql. The code below runs without any compilation error but the notFoundException is not getting called. Any help would be appriciated.

```
declare
    abc exception;
    notFoundException exception;
    cursor c1(dd number) is select first_name from employees where salary = dd;

begin
    for i in c1(&t)
    loop
        if(c1%rowcount!=1) then
            raise abc;
        elsif(c1%notfound) then
            raise notFoundException;
        else 
            dbms_output.put_line(i.first_name);
        end if;
end loop;
Exception  
        when abc then
            dbms_output.put_line('abc');
            insert into messages values('too many rows exception');         
        when notFoundException then
            dbms_output.put_line('notFoundException');
            insert into messages values('Nobody with this salary : ');
end;
/
```

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this code.  If the query returns no rows, you won't ever enter your loop.  `c1%rowcount` is the number of rows that have been fetched so far not how many rows will be fetched.  `c1%notfound` will never be `true` in this case.  I'm guessing this is a homework assignment and I'm not sure what it is that you're actually trying to accomplish.  Perhaps you want to do a `select into` and then handle the `no_data_found` and `too_many_rows` execptions.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the below anonymous block and try

```
`SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE

first_name_in    employees.first_name%ROWTYPE;
Salary_in        employees.salary%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

Salary_in:=&Salary;

SELECT first_name
INTO first_name_in
FROM employees
WHERE salary = Salary_in;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nobody with this salary :'||Salary_in);
INSERT 
 INTO messages 
VALUES ('NO_DATA_FOUND exception');

WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Too many with this salary :'||Salary_in); 
INSERT 
 INTO messages 
VALUES ('TOO_MANY_ROWS exception');

WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('select failed with error'||SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,100))
INSERT 
 INTO messages 
VALUES (SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,100));

COMMIT;
END;
/`
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read about cursors in PL/SQL.
A cursor for loop will loop through every record that is retrieved in the cursor. If no data is found, execution will never proceed inside the loop, hence no data found exception will not be raised inside the loop. Your code should be like this

```
declare
    abc exception;
    notFoundException exception;
    lv_first_name varchar2(240);
    cursor c1(dd number) is select first_name from employees where salary = dd;

begin

    open c1;
    fetch c1 into lv_first_name;
    if(c1%rowcount > 1) then
      raise abc;
    elsif(c1%notfound) then
      raise notFoundException;
    else 
      dbms_output.put_line(lv_first_name);
    end if;
    close c1;

Exception  
        when abc then
            dbms_output.put_line('abc');
            insert into messages values('too many rows exception');         
        when notFoundException then
            dbms_output.put_line('notFoundException');
            insert into messages values('Nobody with this salary : ');
end;
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the cursor.

Comment: there were these minor mistakes at open c1(&t) and about the closing cursor. i did remove the for loop and tried but still its not working. I am a beginner so maybe i need lot of reading and practicing. thanks for the answer. @Dinesh

Comment: Yes PLSQL is not hard to learn. Practice can make you better. All the best. Please share the code that is still not working for you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use cursor attributes when using FOR LOOP. You could just query the records and make decision afterwards. Here is a running example (I didn't have the employees table, so made up a stub). The convenient thing about FOR LOOP is that you don't have to worry about closing the cursor.

```
DECLARE
  abc               EXCEPTION;
  notfoundexception EXCEPTION;
  CURSOR c1(dd NUMBER) IS
    SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT MOD(rownum, 3) salary
                  ,rownum first_name
              FROM dual
            CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10)
     WHERE salary = dd;

  v_count NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN c1(2) LOOP
    v_count := v_count + 1;

    IF (v_count > 1) THEN
      RAISE abc;
    END IF;

    dbms_output.put_line(i.first_name);
  END LOOP;

  IF (v_count = 0) THEN
    RAISE notfoundexception;
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN abc THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('abc');
    --insert into messages values('too many rows exception');         
  WHEN notfoundexception THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('notFoundException');
    --insert into messages values('Nobody with this salary : ');
END;
/
```